# Ionic 4 / Cordova - Get Device Accounts

Tags: android, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 4 with Cordova and I was wondering if there's a possibility to get the device's email.

According to the Ionic's [docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/device-accounts), to get the device accounts is as simple as writing:

```
import { DeviceAccounts } from '@ionic-native/device-accounts/ngx';

    constructor(private deviceAccounts: DeviceAccounts) { }

    ...

    this.deviceAccounts.get()
      .then(accounts => console.log(accounts))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Sounds simple, right? well... the [plugin it's referring to](https://github.com/danielsogl/cordova-device-accounts) is not maintainable, and it doesn't work either (the promise are never resolved).

Is there any other known approach to get the device accounts/emails?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue, just as of this week, the documentation has been updated.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device-accounts

The new repository that is being maintained is the following:

https://github.com/xUnholy/cordova-device-accounts

The old version no longer works with Android 8.0.0 because of a permission change that no longer allows emails to be visible automatically.

Comment: im using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device-accounts but still it is not working. Is it working to u ?

Comment: Yes it is working for myself, could you please post the error or issue you're facing. Also have you checked the repo link I mentioned above?

Comment: im not getting any errors... it is just returning empty array. NOTE im testing this on Android 9

Comment: I am also observing the behaviour that an empty array is returned on Android 10. In AndroidManifest I have set both GET_ACCOUNTS and GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED. I have also ensured that all permissions are enabled for my app under "Settings" > "Apps & Notifications" > "Advanced" > "Permission manager" > "Contacts".

Comment: On Android 6.0.1 it returns an array of account as expected, so the issue is (probably) related to Android 8 and above.

Comment: Issue added: https://github.com/xUnholy/cordova-device-accounts-v2/issues/15

Comment: I've tested with Android 8.0 and it was working for me at the time, I'm going to redirect all communication to the issue on the repository, however please include versions of device, and the plugin as this may also impact the results because an empty array being returned was an old bug previously. Also please check the other options that are available not solely the Get() func. I personally use the getPermissions() by memory.